# PDF search not working on second Search Service Application

Tags: 2010, search, crawling, pdf

We have configured a second SSA specifically for a web app. Searching PDF works great for webapps that are associated to the first SSA but not for the second. I have added PDF as one of the file types for the second SSA and ran a full crawl but it returns nothing. Is there any thing else that needs to be done to enable PDF crawling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by resetting the search index, restarting the search service and doing a full crawl.